# Evaluating $\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4y-y^2}}x^2dxdy$ using polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, jacobian

Evaluate $$\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4y-y^2}}x^2dxdy$$ using polar coordinates.

My try:
The region is as shown below:

[image]

As i can notice $\theta$ is going from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. But i am confused in finding limits for $r$?

Comment: What are the equations for $y=1$ and $x=\sqrt{4y-y^2}$ in polar?